# Java not recognized when running a shell script from Jenkins

Tags: java, shell, jenkins, jenkins-scriptler

I am trying to run/invoke a java program on a Jenkins slave using Jenkins. I am getting the error Javac is not recognized. But when i invoke the same program from the jenkins slave host directly, the java program perfectly works fine. I tried setting the java home by export $java_home on the shell script itself but it doesn't seem to do any help. Checked the versions of java and all looked okay. Any thoughts/ideas??

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what have you tried; and exact messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effective value PATH variable in that script does not have java.  There are many ways to solve it.

#### Option 1

User absolute path to your java. You already have JAVA_HOME defined. So refer to java as $JAVA_HOME/bin/java ...

#### Option 2

Variant of above. Add $JAVA_HOME/bin to PATH. Like below

```
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

#### Option 3

Further variation on above. Allow Jenkins to [install JDK](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tool+Auto-Installation) and set environment variable [pointing to installation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Tool+Environment+Plugin). Use this environment variable in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jayan. 
Option 1 is not feasible because my java program/app contains references to other java programs/dependencies. Option 2: Already tried and din't help. Option 3 definitely works but can't do it because of space limitations.

Comment: I have settled with Option 3.

Answer (score 0):

I specified the absolute value of Java path in Environment variables in Node Properties like below

JAVA_HOME

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17

And it worked